# Why can I see the 5D0 to 7F3 transition in the trivalent Eu?

Tags: solid-state-physics, atomic-physics, spectroscopy

According to the selection rules of the intra-configurational f-f transitions, if the J of the initial or final state is zero, a transition with $\Delta J = 3$ is forbidden by electrical dipole, magnetic dipole and electric quadripole.

So why are these lines so often detected in photoluminescence spectroscopy?

Answer (score 2):

This is, I'm afraid, a rather vague answer since it's a long time since I studied this and I no longer have access to the relevant journals. Anyhow, while the transition is forbidden for an isolated Europium atom it is allowed in the crystal because the light interacts with the crystal field surrounding the Europium atom so it's not a pure dipole interaction.

If your college has access to the Journal of Physics look up the paper by J. E. Lowther J Phys (C) 1974 7 p4393. Vague recollections and some Googling suggest this explains how to calculate transition probabilities including contributions from the crystal field. It's available online [here](http://www.jiscjournalarchives.ac.uk/browse/iop/0022-3719_issues/7_1974.html).